# How to switch from Mysql 5.7 to 8.0 in Magento 2.4

Tags: database, magento2.2.4

I was developing Magento 2 with MySql 5.7 but on production server there is MySql 8 installed which is giving me some query errors.

After following [a guide](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/mysql.html#upgrading-from-mysql-57-to-mysql-8) of migrating from MySql 5.7 to MySql 8.0 it states in step 6.:

```
6. In the Magento admin, set the database engine to MySQL 8.
```

Where in Magento admin is this option, I can't find it anywhere...?

Comment: dont worry about it

Comment: So there is no such option and I have to fix my code not to have error in MySql 8 I guess